How do I use the running ssh agent when calling wsl commands from cmd
I am trying to call rsync from cmd using "wsl rsync" however it always asks for my ssh key password. How can I use the running agent within wsl instead of needing to type my password every time I invoke the command?

I think we need more information. Where are you trying to rsync to and from. Do you have ssh keys setup?  I have my ssh keys setup in the WSL host and works without asking for a password. Without them it does ask for a password. (I tested with scp but should be the same)

I am trying to rsync from my local windows machine to a linux box. Rsync works fine when I call it from within wsl, but im trying to automate something and it needs to be called from the command line. I currently have my keys setup in wsl using keychain to automatically load and start ssh-agent


How can I use the running agent within wsl instead of needing to type my password every time I invoke the command?

You'll need to do at least two things (and preferably a third):
Configure ssh-agent
You don't mention whether you have your key added to an SSH agent.  An agent is what caches your key and allows you to reuse it without retyping the password.
All of your shell sessions must be using the same instance of the ssh-agent in order to type the password in one session and have it available in the others.
See this question for some possibilities - Ironically, essentially every answer except for the accepted one is about reusing the same ssh-agent.  The accepted answer still starts a separate ssh-agent for each session, so that won't work for this use-case.
I highly recommend the Funtoo Keychain answer for reasons that will be more clear in the "Keep WSL Running" section below.  Honestly, I'd probably recommend it even if it weren't for that, since Keychain is available in most package managers (e.g., sudo apt install keychain) and is very convenient.
Ensure .bashrc is loaded
When running wsl rsync, the command is run inside a Bash that is not interactive and not a login shell.  This means that your ~/.bashrc (which is where your SSH agent is configured) is not normally loaded. See this answer for (way too much) detail.
Short-answer solution is to run:
wsl -e bash -lic rsync

This will tell Bash to load your startup configuration.
Make sure WSL continues running
By default, if no user-initiated processes are running inside a WSL distribution, WSL automatically terminates it after a short period.
If you want to keep it running, you'll need some longer-running process that prevents WSL from terminating.
keychain, mentioned above, has the nice side-effect of continuing to run in the background. As a result, until you manually kill the keychain process, WSL will continue running, and the cached password will be available.
